# Reading an execl file (.xlsx) file placed in s3 and converting into csv

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have an excel file that is placed in S3, I wan to read it and convert it into csv.
While trying to achieve this using lambda, I got into a problem where I was not able to install pandas and xlrd libraries.

Is there any other way to read the excel file apart from pandas and xlrd.
And if there is not, how can i install the pandas library in lambda; coz i already tried adding layer also into the lambda function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles to include external packages such as

```
pip install -t . pandas
```

where `.` indicates the current location. You can install the package into your project and zip, upload it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

So, the structure of your python might be

```
top location
└ package 1
└ package 2
your project main
and so on...
```